# PHP Soap request for an array with stdclass objects

Tags: php, xml, arrays, soap, stdclass

I made a Soap request that gives me an array filled with STDclasses.

I want the results from the Articlesummary so i can use the ID's for finding the right articles.

But all code i tried for now gives me problems with the STDclass and array combination

```
array(1) { 

["GetArticleSummariesResult"]=> object(stdClass)
#3 (2) { ["Errors"]=> object(stdClass)#4 (0) { } 

["ArticleSummaries"]=> object(stdClass)#5 (1) {

["ArticleSummary"]=> array(27) { 
[0]=> object(stdClass)#6 (4) { ["ID"]=> int(21557) ["Created"]=> string(19) "2010-05-06     15:54:50" ["Modified"]=> string(19) "2010-05-25 19:54:09" ["Active"]=> bool(true) } 
[1]=> object(stdClass)#7 (4) { ["ID"]=> int(21638) ["Created"]=> string(19) "2010-05-06 15:54:50" ["Modified"]=> string(19) "2010-05-25 19:54:09" ["Active"]=> bool(true) }
[2]=> object(stdClass)#8 (4) { ["ID"]=> int(21260) ["Created"]=> string(19) "2010-05-06 15:54:50" ["Modified"]=> string(19) "2010-05-25 19:54:09" ["Active"]=> bool(true) } 
[3]=> object(stdClass)#9 (4) { ["ID"]=> int(26664) ["Created"]=> string(19) "2010-05-25 19:54:07" ["Modified"]=> string(19) "2010-05-25 19:54:07" ["Active"]=> bool(true) } 
[4]=> object(stdClass)#10 (4) { ["ID"]=> int(22165) ["Created"]=> string(19) "2010-05-25 19:54:07" ["Modified"]=> string(19) "2010-05-25 19:54:07" ["Active"]=> bool(true) } 
[5]=> object(stdClass)#11 (4) { ["ID"]=> int(24166) ["Created"]=> string(19) "2010-05-25 19:54:07" ["Modified"]=> string(19) "2010-08-16 22:44:38" ["Active"]=> bool(true) } 
[6]=> object(stdClass)#12 (4) { ["ID"]=> int(26167) ["Created"]=> string(19) "2010-05-25 19:54:07" ["Modified"]=> string(19) "2010-05-25 19:54:07" ["Active"]=> bool(true) } 
[7]=> object(stdClass)#13 (4) { ["ID"]=> int(26170) ["Created"]=> string(19) "2010-05-25 19:54:07" ["Modified"]=> string(19) "2011-05-05 09:04:19" ["Active"]=> bool(true) } 
[8]=> object(stdClass)#14 (4) { ["ID"]=> int(29471) ["Created"]=> string(19) "2010-07-02 11:59:26" ["Modified"]=> string(19) "2010-07-02 11:59:26" ["Active"]=> bool(true) } 
[9]=> object(stdClass)#15 (4) { ["ID"]=> int(21157) ["Created"]=> string(19) "2011-03-04 09:34:11" ["Modified"]=> string(19) "2012-06-12 11:34:44" ["Active"]=> bool(true) } 
[10]=> object(stdClass)#16 (4) { ["ID"]=> int(272876) ["Created"]=> string(19) "2011-04-11 12:14:29" ["Modified"]=> string(19) "2012-09-04 14:25:07" ["Active"]=> bool(true) } 
[11]=> object(stdClass)#17 (4) { ["ID"]=> int(28328) ["Created"]=> string(19) "2011-05-03 12:25:07" ["Modified"]=> string(19) "2011-05-03 12:25:07" ["Active"]=> bool(true) } 
[12]=> object(stdClass)#18 (4) { ["ID"]=> int(226752) ["Created"]=> string(19) "2011-05-17 00:14:51" ["Modified"]=> string(19) "2011-05-25 10:48:22" ["Active"]=> bool(true) } 
[13]=> object(stdClass)#19 (4) { ["ID"]=> int(2231971) ["Created"]=> string(19) "2011-05-18 16:37:50" ["Modified"]=> string(19) "2011-05-18 16:40:12" ["Active"]=> bool(true) } 
[14]=> object(stdClass)#20 (4) { ["ID"]=> int(2970219) ["Created"]=> string(19) "2011-09-05 10:34:14" ["Modified"]=> string(19) "2011-09-05 10:34:14" ["Active"]=> bool(true) } 
[15]=> object(stdClass)#21 (4) { ["ID"]=> int(24178) ["Created"]=> string(19) "2011-11-18 18:54:16" ["Modified"]=> string(19) "2011-11-23 13:44:18" ["Active"]=> bool(true) } 
[16]=> object(stdClass)#22 (4) { ["ID"]=> int(3160171) ["Created"]=> string(19) "2012-01-18 10:55:09" ["Modified"]=> string(19) "2012-01-18 14:04:18" ["Active"]=> bool(true) } 
[17]=> object(stdClass)#23 (4) { ["ID"]=> int(394795) ["Created"]=> string(19) "2012-02-10 10:14:15" ["Modified"]=> string(19) "2012-02-10 10:14:16" ["Active"]=> bool(true) } 
[18]=> object(stdClass)#24 (4) { ["ID"]=> int(3236961) ["Created"]=> string(19) "2012-03-12 11:44:45" ["Modified"]=> string(19) "2012-03-12 13:34:37" ["Active"]=> bool(true) } 
[19]=> object(stdClass)#25 (4) { ["ID"]=> int(343578) ["Created"]=> string(19) "2012-06-07 15:24:07" ["Modified"]=> string(19) "2012-06-11 09:44:22" ["Active"]=> bool(true) } 
[20]=> object(stdClass)#26 (4) { ["ID"]=> int(3376400) ["Created"]=> string(19) "2012-07-03 13:55:40" ["Modified"]=> string(19) "2012-07-03 13:55:40" ["Active"]=> bool(true) } 
[21]=> object(stdClass)#27 (4) { ["ID"]=> int(33622) ["Created"]=> string(19) "2012-07-25 10:24:24" ["Modified"]=> string(19) "2012-07-25 10:24:24" ["Active"]=> bool(true) } 
[22]=> object(stdClass)#28 (4) { ["ID"]=> int(3404088) ["Created"]=> string(19) "2012-07-25 14:34:20" ["Modified"]=> string(19) "2012-07-25 14:34:20" ["Active"]=> bool(true) } 
[23]=> object(stdClass)#29 (4) { ["ID"]=> int(35046) ["Created"]=> string(19) "2012-07-26 15:14:13" ["Modified"]=> string(19) "2012-08-20 11:04:20" ["Active"]=> bool(true) } 
[24]=> object(stdClass)#30 (4) { ["ID"]=> int(37926) ["Created"]=> string(19) "2012-09-04 14:44:09" ["Modified"]=> string(19) "2012-09-04 14:44:09" ["Active"]=> bool(true) } 
[25]=> object(stdClass)#31 (4) { ["ID"]=> int(36657) ["Created"]=> string(19) "2012-09-17 16:14:53" ["Modified"]=> string(19) "2012-09-17 16:14:53" ["Active"]=> bool(true) } 
[26]=> object(stdClass)#32 (4) { ["ID"]=> int(32328) ["Created"]=> string(19) "2012-10-08 10:34:42" ["Modified"]=> string(19) "2012-10-08 10:44:33" ["Active"]=> bool(true) }

=} } } }
```

Can somebody help me please too find a way to get the results.

```
<wsdl:operation name="GetArticleSummaries"><wsdl:documentation>Get publication summaries for publications that where last created/modified after the given date. 
                lastModified not specified will return all active publications.
                RequestedPropertyTypes (PropertyTypes) not specified will return all allowed types.
                Please use RequestedPropertyTypes instead of PropertyTypes, PropertyTypes will be removed in future versions.</wsdl:documentation><wsdl:input message="tns:GetPublicationSummariesSoapIn"/><wsdl:output message="tns:GetPublicationSummariesSoapOut"/>


<wsdl:message name="GetArticleSummariesSoapIn"><wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetPublicationSummaries"/></wsdl:message>


<s:element name="GetArticleSummaries"><s:complexType><s:sequence><s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="LastModified" nillable="true" type="s:dateTime"/><s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="PropertyTypes" type="tns:PropertyType"/><s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="RequestedPropertyTypes" type="tns:ArrayOfPropertyType"/></s:sequence></s:complexType></s:element>




$result = $client->GetArticleSummaries(array('ArticleId'));
$array = (array)$result;
var_dump($array);








object(stdClass)#2 (1) { ["GetPublicationSummariesResult"]=> object(stdClass)#3 (2) { ["Errors"]=> object(stdClass)#4 (0) { } ["PublicationSummaries"]=> object(stdClass)#5 (1) { ["PublicationSummary"]=> array(27) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#6 (4) { ["ID"]=> int(1441657) ["Created"]=> string(19) "2010-05-06 15:54:50" ["Modified"]=> string(19) "2010-05-25 19:54:09" ["Active"]=> bool(true) } [1]=> object(stdClass)#7 (4) { ["ID"]=> int(1441658) ["Created"]=> string(19) "2010-05-06 15:54:50" ["Modified"]=> string(19) "2010-05-25 19:54:09" ["Active"]=> bool(true) } [2]=> object(stdClass)#8 (4) { ["ID"]=> int(1441660) ["Created"]=> string(19) "2010-05-06 15:54:50" ["Modified"]=> string(19) "2010-05-25 19:54:09" ["Active"]=> bool(true) } [3]=> object(stdClass)#9 (4) { ["ID"]=> int(1456164) ["Created"]=> string(19) "2010-05-25 19:54:07" ["Modified"]=> string(19) "2010-05-25 19:54:07" ["Active"]=> bool(true) } [4]=> object(stdClass)#10 (4) { ["ID"]=> int(1456165) ["Created"]=> string(19) "2010-05-25 19:54:07" ["Modified"]=> string(19) "2010-05-25 19:54:07" ["Active"]=> bool(true) } [5]=> object(stdClass)#11 (4) { ["ID"]=> int(1456166) ["Created"]=> string(19) "2010-05-25 19:54:07" ["Modified"]=> string(19) "2010-08-16 22:44:38" ["Active"]=> bool(true) } [6]=> object(stdClass)#12 (4) { ["ID"]=> int(1456167) ["Created"]=> string(19) "2010-05-25 19:54:07" ["Modified"]=> string(19) "2010-05-25 19:54:07" ["Active"]=> bool(true) } [7]=> object(stdClass)#13 (4) { ["ID"]=> int(1456170) ["Created"]=> string(19) "2010-05-25 19:54:07" ["Modified"]=> string(19) "2011-05-05 09:04:19" ["Active"]=> bool(true) } [8]=> object(stdClass)#14 (4) { ["ID"]=> int(1489471) ["Created"]=> string(19) "2010-07-02 11:59:26" ["Modified"]=> string(19) "2010-07-02 11:59:26" ["Active"]=> bool(true) } [9]=> object(stdClass)#15 (4) { ["ID"]=> int(1721157) ["Created"]=> string(19) "2011-03-04 09:34:11" ["Modified"]=> string(19) "2012-06-12 11:34:44" ["Active"]=> bool(true) } [10]=> object(stdClass)#16 (4) { ["ID"]=> int(1772876) ["Created"]=> string(19) "2011-04-11 12:14:29" ["Modified"]=> string(19) "2012-09-04 14:25:07" ["Active"]=> bool(true) } [11]=> object(stdClass)#17 (4) { ["ID"]=> int(1808328) ["Created"]=> string(19) "2011-05-03 12:25:07" ["Modified"]=> string(19) "2011-05-03 12:25:07" ["Active"]=> bool(true) } [12]=> object(stdClass)#18 (4) { ["ID"]=> int(1826752) ["Created"]=> string(19) "2011-05-17 00:14:51" ["Modified"]=> string(19) "2011-05-25 10:48:22" ["Active"]=> bool(true) } [13]=> object(stdClass)#19 (4) { ["ID"]=> int(1830971) ["Created"]=> string(19) "2011-05-18 16:37:50" ["Modified"]=> string(19) "2011-05-18 16:40:12" ["Active"]=> bool(true) } [14]=> object(stdClass)#20 (4) { ["ID"]=> int(1970219) ["Created"]=> string(19) "2011-09-05 10:34:14" ["Modified"]=> string(19) "2011-09-05 10:34:14" ["Active"]=> bool(true) } [15]=> object(stdClass)#21 (4) { ["ID"]=> int(2084178) ["Created"]=> string(19) "2011-11-18 18:54:16" ["Modified"]=> string(19) "2011-11-23 13:44:18" ["Active"]=> bool(true) } [16]=> object(stdClass)#22 (4) { ["ID"]=> int(2160171) ["Created"]=> string(19) "2012-01-18 10:55:09" ["Modified"]=> string(19) "2012-01-18 14:04:18" ["Active"]=> bool(true) } [17]=> object(stdClass)#23 (4) { ["ID"]=> int(2194795) ["Created"]=> string(19) "2012-02-10 10:14:15" ["Modified"]=> string(19) "2012-02-10 10:14:16" ["Active"]=> bool(true) } [18]=> object(stdClass)#24 (4) { ["ID"]=> int(2236961) ["Created"]=> string(19) "2012-03-12 11:44:45" ["Modified"]=> string(19) "2012-03-12 13:34:37" ["Active"]=> bool(true) } [19]=> object(stdClass)#25 (4) { ["ID"]=> int(2343578) ["Created"]=> string(19) "2012-06-07 15:24:07" ["Modified"]=> string(19) "2012-06-11 09:44:22" ["Active"]=> bool(true) } [20]=> object(stdClass)#26 (4) { ["ID"]=> int(2376900) ["Created"]=> string(19) "2012-07-03 13:55:40" ["Modified"]=> string(19) "2012-07-03 13:55:40" ["Active"]=> bool(true) } [21]=> object(stdClass)#27 (4) { ["ID"]=> int(2403622) ["Created"]=> string(19) "2012-07-25 10:24:24" ["Modified"]=> string(19) "2012-07-25 10:24:24" ["Active"]=> bool(true) } [22]=> object(stdClass)#28 (4) { ["ID"]=> int(2404088) ["Created"]=> string(19) "2012-07-25 14:34:20" ["Modified"]=> string(19) "2012-07-25 14:34:20" ["Active"]=> bool(true) } [23]=> object(stdClass)#29 (4) { ["ID"]=> int(2405046) ["Created"]=> string(19) "2012-07-26 15:14:13" ["Modified"]=> string(19) "2012-08-20 11:04:20" ["Active"]=> bool(true) } [24]=> object(stdClass)#30 (4) { ["ID"]=> int(2447926) ["Created"]=> string(19) "2012-09-04 14:44:09" ["Modified"]=> string(19) "2012-09-04 14:44:09" ["Active"]=> bool(true) } [25]=> object(stdClass)#31 (4) { ["ID"]=> int(2466657) ["Created"]=> string(19) "2012-09-17 16:14:53" ["Modified"]=> string(19) "2012-09-17 16:14:53" ["Active"]=> bool(true) } [26]=> object(stdClass)#32 (4) { ["ID"]=> int(2502328) ["Created"]=> string(19) "2012-10-08 10:34:42" ["Modified"]=> string(19) "2012-10-08 10:44:33" ["Active"]=> bool(true) } } } } }
```

Comment: Can you please view the page source of the object you called `var_dump()` or `print_r()` on and copy/paste from the source?  After pasting it here, highlight and ctl-k to format a code block.  This is incomprehensible as it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an outer array which is associative. Its only key is `GetArticleSummariesResult`.  `ArticleSummaries` is an object in that array having one property `ArticleSummary`, which is an array of objects.  The values you are looking for (`ID`) are object properties.

```
$outer_array: array, access with []
GetArticleSummariesResult: object stdClass
ArticleSummaries: object stdClass, access properties with ->
ArticleSummary: array with numeric indices, access with []
Objects in ArticleSummary array: object stdClass, access properties with ->
```

Examples:

```
echo $outer_array['GetArticleSummariesResult']->ArticleSummaries->ArticleSummary[0]->ID;
// 21557
echo $outer_array['GetArticleSummariesResult']->ArticleSummaries->ArticleSummary[0]->Created;
// 2010-05-06     15:54:50
echo $outer_array['GetArticleSummariesResult']->ArticleSummaries->ArticleSummary[5]->ID;
// 24166
```

In a loop:

```
foreach ($outer_array['GetArticleSummariesResult']->ArticleSummaries->ArticleSummary as $summary) {
  // Print the id and created date
  echo $summary->ID . " " . $summary->Created . "\n";
}
```

Comment: That gives also the same Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Comment: @user1744878 I updated above.  I misread your output due to its missing indentation.

Comment: @user1744878 I just updated it as you were commenting. See above now -- `ArticleSummaries` is an object inside `GetArticleSummariesResult`

Comment: Still the same Fatal Error i'am trying now several options

Comment: @user1744878 Like I originally asked, view the _page source_ of the dumped object, so you can see all the correct indentation. Copy it into your question with the indentation intact, highlight and ctl-k.

Comment: $result = $client->GetArticleSummaries(array('ArticleId'));
$array = (array)$result;
var_dump($array);

Comment: I updated my answer, for some reason stack overflow doesn't show it in a correct way but also in my last answer i write down the code

Comment: The page source is in the original answer now, but stackoverflow refuse too show it like code

Comment: @user1744878 You are misunderstanding me.  I need to see the _output_ of `var_dump($result);` from the browser page source, which will look somewhat like what is posted way up at the top, but with correct indentation.  Why are you casting `$result` to an array with `$array = (array)$result`?  If it's an object, use it as an object.

Comment: I places the $result object in my question. Maybe i need too forgot the array for now and focus on this object. I'am now searching information about stdclasses

Comment: The object you posted is the result of `GetPublicationSummaries` not `GetArticleSummaries` as you originally asked, and it _still_ isn't the properly formatted, indented output I asked for. Don't cast it to an array. Use `$result->GetPublicationSummariesResult->PublicationSummaries->PublicationSummary[0]->ID`

Answer (score 0):

```
    $result = array(); //your result

    foreach($result["GetArticleSummariesResult"]->ArticleSummaries->ArticleSummary as $sum)
    {

       //Search ID u want
       if($sum->ID == 009831)
          {
              //I got you.
          }
     }
```

Comment: That results in Cannot use object of type stdClass as array. That eeror i got the whole day.

Comment: $result = $client->GetArticleSummaries(array('ArticleId'));
$array = (array)$result;
var_dump($array);